# Joins associations in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, join

I need to count the number of views of an asset, this asset being embeded in multiple blogs, each blog generating multiple view for that asset.

[image: UML diagram]

I'm using **Rails 3** and I was expecting the following to work:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :embeds
end

class Embed < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :asset
  has_many :views
end

class View < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :embed
end

class Assets < ApplicationController
  def show
    asset = Asset.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @views = asset.embeds.views.count
  end
end
```

Of course, it didn't work as expected. Why is that?

And what would be the best approach to this? (joins, includes, raw SQL...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a has_many :through

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :embeds
  has_many :views, :through => :embeds
end
```

Then you just do this:

```
@views = asset.views.size
```